# How to switch Post Method to file_get_contents and file_put_contents?

Tags: php

I got a text file (testfile.txt) containing

```
127.0.0.1:80
127.0.0.1:90
127.0.0.1:100 127.0.0.1:230
127.0.0.1:110
127.0.0.1:200
127.0.0.1:201 127.0.0.1:45
127.0.0.1:86
(...)
```

In order to fix lines such as 127.0.0.1:100 127.0.0.1:230 and 127.0.0.1:201127.0.0.1:45 I'm using this script (POST METHOD):

```
$listValue = "";

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['list']))
        $res = preg_match_all("/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:\d+/", $_POST['list'], $match);

        if($res)
        foreach($match[0] as $value)
        $listValue .= $value."\n";
```

and on Submit:

```
echo trim($listValue);
```

Script returns:

```
127.0.0.1:80
127.0.0.1:90
127.0.0.1:100
127.0.0.1:230
127.0.0.1:110
127.0.0.1:200
127.0.0.1:201
127.0.0.1:86
(...)
```

I need this script to read from testfile.txt and to save to testfile.txt. 
Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Take a look at `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$list = file_get_contents('testfile.txt');
$res = preg_match_all("/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:\d+/", $list, $match);

if($res) {
    foreach($match[0] as $value)
        $listValue .= $value."\n";
    file_put_contents('testfile.txt', trim($listValue));
}
```

Edit: Also, instead of the regexp, you could do a simple str_replace(' ', "\n", $list)